# TAP results do not show up during execution time, if a TestClassSetup is present

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I have a problem. We use the Matlab testing framework to analyze our codebase. To track the results in our CI system TeamCity we use the TAP-format. Here we have the following problem:

If a test includes a TestClassSetup section, the TAP results show up only at the end, and not during the exection. This results in a few issues for us:

- Timestamps created by the CI system might not be correct
- If informative output is given within a test-case, it is not shown together with the assertion statment.

We use the following (simplified) snippet to identify out TestSuite and execute it:

```
testSuite = matlab.unittest.TestSuite.fromFolder('.');
runner = matlab.unittest.TestRunner.withNoPlugins();
runner.addPlugin(matlab.unittest.plugins.TAPPlugin.producingOriginalFormat());
results = runner.run(testSuite);
```

With the following two classes the issue is reproducible (the content is of course made up & meaningless...):

```
classdef SomeTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
   properties (TestParameter)
       param = {1, 2};
       param2 = {1, 2};
   end        
   methods (TestClassSetup)
       function someSetup(testCase)
           pause(0.1);
       end
   end    
   methods (Test)
       function testMethod(self, param, param2)
          fprintf('I''m here, with the params: %f/%f\n', param, param2);
          pause(0.1);
          self.assertGreaterThan(param, param2); 
       end
   end    
end

classdef SomeOtherTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
   properties (TestParameter)
       param = {1, 2};
       param2 = {1, 2};
   end    

   methods (Test)
       function testMethod(self, param, param2)
          fprintf('I''m here, with the params: %f/%f\n', param, param2);
          pause(0.1);
          self.assertGreaterThan(param, param2); 
       end
   end

end
```

If you copy all three files into one folder, and execute the runner, you'll see the output (assertions are simplified):

```
1..8
I'm here, with the params: 1.000000/1.000000
not ok 1 - SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=1,param2=1)
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=1,param2=1) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
# 
I'm here, with the params: 1.000000/2.000000
not ok 2 - SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=1,param2=2)
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=1,param2=2) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
# 
I'm here, with the params: 2.000000/1.000000
ok 3 - SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=2,param2=1)
I'm here, with the params: 2.000000/2.000000
not ok 4 - SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=2,param2=2)
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=2,param2=2) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
# 
I'm here, with the params: 1.000000/1.000000
I'm here, with the params: 1.000000/2.000000
I'm here, with the params: 2.000000/1.000000
I'm here, with the params: 2.000000/2.000000
not ok 5 - SomeTest/testMethod(param=1,param2=1)
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeTest/testMethod(param=1,param2=1) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
# 
not ok 6 - SomeTest/testMethod(param=1,param2=2)
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeTest/testMethod(param=1,param2=2) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
# 
ok 7 - SomeTest/testMethod(param=2,param2=1)
not ok 8 - SomeTest/testMethod(param=2,param2=2)
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeTest/testMethod(param=2,param2=2) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
```

What I would expect is that also in the second case the Assertion statements (and the ok / not ok TAP flags) are aligned with the fprintf-statements.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the presence of TestClassSetup "defers" the printing of the TAP output is because the TAP output is a streaming format and if there is any TestClassSetup code the frame work actually does not yet know whether the tests will pass or not. For example, if you have a failure in TestClassTeardown (or through an addTeardown function call in TestClassSetup), the end result is that all the tests that shared the TestClassSetup code will fail.

However, given its a streaming format the TAPPLugin wants to print out the result as soon as it knows the result. There is actually a TestRunnerPlugin  method specifically designed for this case, the [reportFinalizedResult method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.testrunnerplugin.reportfinalizedresult.html).

The fundamental issue here is that I would recommend you avoid printing to the log using disp or fprintf. This is less ideal because the plugins don't have any insight into any of the information printed using fprintf. Also, you can't redirect this information anywhere other than the matlab command line.

However, if you instead using the [testCase.log](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testcase.log.html) method you will get the diagnostics in the right place and it will be more flexible. You will be able to log it at different levels so you can turn it on or off as you please and control whether you want to see it. It will also not only go to the command line but will go much more nicely into the TAP stream as well as the junit xml and the pdf/html test reports and so on. For your case it looks like the following:

```
runner = matlab.unittest.TestRunner.withNoPlugins();
runner.addPlugin(matlab.unittest.plugins.TAPPlugin.producingOriginalFormat());
results = runner.run(testSuite);
```

First you run and you don't see any of the log calls because it was logged at verbosity "3" and the default is lower (level 1 I believe)

```
1..8
not ok 1 - SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value1)
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value1) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
not ok 2 - SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value2)
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value2) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
ok 3 - SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value2,param2=value1)
not ok 4 - SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value2,param2=value2)
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value2,param2=value2) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
not ok 5 - SomeTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value1)
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value1) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
not ok 6 - SomeTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value2)
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value2) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
ok 7 - SomeTest/testMethod(param=value2,param2=value1)
not ok 8 - SomeTest/testMethod(param=value2,param2=value2)
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeTest/testMethod(param=value2,param2=value2) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
```

However, if you configure the tap plugin (or the version 13 tap plugin or the report plugin etc) to log at level threee then you see these diagnostics and they are at the expected location as well:

```
runner = matlab.unittest.TestRunner.withNoPlugins();
runner.addPlugin(matlab.unittest.plugins.TAPPlugin.producingOriginalFormat('Verbosity', 3));
results = runner.run(testSuite);
```

You see the output. Also try the TAPVersion 13, the structured output that provides might provide an even better result.

```
1..8
not ok 1 - SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value1)
# ================================================================================
# [Detailed] Diagnostic logged (2018-08-09 16:47:18): I'm here, with the params: 1.000000/1.000000
# ================================================================================
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value1) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
not ok 2 - SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value2)
# ================================================================================
# [Detailed] Diagnostic logged (2018-08-09 16:47:19): I'm here, with the params: 1.000000/2.000000
# ================================================================================
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value2) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
ok 3 - SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value2,param2=value1)
# ================================================================================
# [Detailed] Diagnostic logged (2018-08-09 16:47:19): I'm here, with the params: 2.000000/1.000000
# ================================================================================
not ok 4 - SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value2,param2=value2)
# ================================================================================
# [Detailed] Diagnostic logged (2018-08-09 16:47:19): I'm here, with the params: 2.000000/2.000000
# ================================================================================
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeOtherTest/testMethod(param=value2,param2=value2) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
not ok 5 - SomeTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value1)
# ================================================================================
# [Detailed] Diagnostic logged (2018-08-09 16:47:19): I'm here, with the params: 1.000000/1.000000
# ================================================================================
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value1) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
not ok 6 - SomeTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value2)
# ================================================================================
# [Detailed] Diagnostic logged (2018-08-09 16:47:19): I'm here, with the params: 1.000000/2.000000
# ================================================================================
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeTest/testMethod(param=value1,param2=value2) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
ok 7 - SomeTest/testMethod(param=value2,param2=value1)
# ================================================================================
# [Detailed] Diagnostic logged (2018-08-09 16:47:20): I'm here, with the params: 2.000000/1.000000
# ================================================================================
not ok 8 - SomeTest/testMethod(param=value2,param2=value2)
# ================================================================================
# [Detailed] Diagnostic logged (2018-08-09 16:47:20): I'm here, with the params: 2.000000/2.000000
# ================================================================================
# ================================================================================
# Assertion failed in SomeTest/testMethod(param=value2,param2=value2) and it did not run to completion.
# ================================================================================
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that sounds exactly like what I want/need! 
And the dynamic teardown is a completely valid argument, why this can be only evaluated at the end.